# How to take a screenshot with QtDBus via org.freedesktop.portal?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, dbus, pyside6

I'm struggling to take a screenshot **on Wayland** through DBus [org.freedesktop.portal.Screenshot](https://flatpak.github.io/xdg-desktop-portal/#gdbus-org.freedesktop.portal.Screenshot) with PySide's [QtDBus](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-dev/PySide6/QtDBus/index.html). There are some [examples for QtDBus](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/examples-dbus.html), but nothing I could transfer to my problem.

In my minimal example (see below) the screenshot request itself seems to work, at least Gnome's screenshot confirmation dialog appears. However, the signal "dbusScreenshotResponse" is never called, so I don't know how to retrieve the response with the URI of the image file.

**Can anyone help me or provide some information to push me in the correct direction?**

PS: I don't want to use any other third party libraries as I want to use as few dependencies as possible and rely on PySide6 anyway.

PPS: Why don't just use Qt's [`grabWindow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html#grabWindow)? Because unfortunately, [it doesn't work under **Wayland**](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-34976), due to its restrictive permission settings (since Gnome 41, I think).

```py
import sys

from PySide6 import QtDBus, QtWidgets, QtCore


class Communication(QtCore.QObject):
    dbusScreenshotResponse = QtCore.Signal(int, object)


class Screenshot(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.com = Communication()

    def grab(self):
        interface = QtDBus.QDBusInterface(
            "org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop",
            "/org/freedesktop/portal/desktop",
            "org.freedesktop.portal.Screenshot",
        )
        reply = interface.call(
            "Screenshot", "", {"interactive": False, "handle_token": "myapp"}
        )
        self.com.dbusScreenshotResponse.connect(self.responseRecevied)
        response_path = self.parse_response_path(reply)
        QtDBus.QDBusConnection.sessionBus().connect(
            "",
            response_path,
            "org.freedesktop.portal.Request",
            "Response",
            self.com,
            "dbusScreenshotResponse",
        )
        print("sent")

    def parse_response_path(self, reply):
        """Interestingly, the response path seems to be known by the reply object,
        but I didn't find a way to access it, other than parsing it from the string
        representation..."""
        s = str(reply).split("[ObjectPath: ")[1]
        s = s.split("]")[0]
        return s

    def responseRecevied(self, *args):
        """This shut be triggered on screenshot confirmation, but it isn't."""
        print("received")
        print(args)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        grabber = Screenshot()
        grabber.grab()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: If you want to avoid third-party dependencies, why are you using dbus with an external screenshot utility? Why not just [use itself Qt to create the screenshot](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscreen.html#grabWindow)?

Comment: @ekhumoro, unfortunately, Qt's `grabWindow()` doesn't work with Wayland. Because of Wayland's security concept, `org.freedesktop.portal.Screenshot` is the only supported way to create screenshots. I'm going to add this info to the Question, and hope that it gets reopened, as the "duplicate" answer isn't a solution in this setting.